# find Specific letters in batch file

Tags: find

i want batch file to search if the txt file have small english letters and numbers,

if the txt file have any letter other than small english letters and numbers it will send him to end

for example:

ــــــــــــ

findstr /m "a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0" test.txt

if %errorlevel% == 0 goto finsih

if %errorlevel% == 1 goto end

:finish

echo the file have small english letters and numbers

pause

exit

:end

echo file have not small english letters and numbers

pause

exit

ـــــــــــ

Comment: I would be helpful if you could ask a concrete question, it's unclear what you want to do / want us to do. 
Also please format your question.

Comment: can any one help my ???